# How to remove Url value after the first / in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have 2 headers with macro partials and am fetching it if the Url contains a particular name so for example lets say current URL is `www.exaple.com/about`
and `www.exaple.com/about/dynamic_url`
now I need to get rid of that dynamic url that mean if the Url contain about then anyway fetch the header.

Am new to umraco any helps will be appreciated.
TIA

```
@{
    if (CurrentPage.Name.ToLower() == "contact" || CurrentPage.Name.ToLower() == "about" || CurrentPage.Name.ToLower() == "hotels" || CurrentPage.Name.ToLower() == "tours")
    {
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro("SecondaryHeader")
    }
    else
    {
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Header")
    }
}
```

this is my code and my URL is http://localhost:64760/tours/suspendisse-tour
so i need to remove /suspendisse-tour/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Name.ToLower()` instead of `CurrentPage.Name.ToLower()`

The extension method AncestorOrSelf(1) will fetch the nth level of node depends on the passed parameter - in my example is 1.

In your example, by using the property `Url` from `CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1)` it will always return the url of its ancestor rather that the current page url.
So instead of /tours/suspendisse-tour, it will always return /tours/.

More detail of this method can be checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916196/umbraco-ancestororselfint-what-does-it-do).

Comment: i have a another option if the default page is home then the Header Partial will be added if not SecondaryHeader will be added!

can you answer for the above condition please.

Comment: @{
    if (CurrentPage.Name.ToLower() == "default" 
    {
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Header")
    }
    else
    {
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro("SecondaryHeader")
    }
}

can we do something like this?

my home is directly goes to the Url so it is hard for me to detect the home  http://localhost:64760/

Comment: I see no problem in your code. Are you sure the home name is "default"?

Comment: no it is not default. i have linked the home page to master

Comment: how to add 2 partial headers in umbraco master page